# How to apply CSS class without affecting global behvior

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using a third party library which has its own CSS class. This is how the DOM looks:

```
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-custom" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
      <div class="toast toast-info" style="display: block;"> ....
```

**This is the class I am overriding to fix the width**

```
.toast-custom {
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**This is the class already provided by framework**

```
#toast-container > div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  width: 46%;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

I am not able to modify the width of the dix without touching `#toast-container > div` but if I make change to `#toast-container > div` it will have a global impact. How can I make use of `.toast-custom` to make the required change?

Comment: #toast-container.toast-custom

Comment: Use greater CSS specificity (learn about that) as Steve G. wrote.

Comment: you want to overwrite `id="toast-container"` or child of `id="toast-container"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you're having is that an `#` "ID selector" (eg. `#my-rule`) is more specific than a `.` "class selector" (eg. `.my-rule`), and the [last] most specific CSS selector (rule) wins.

This should work on any `#toast-containers` that implements `.toast-custom`:

```
/* Note "no space" between */
#toast-container.toast-custom > div {
  ...
}
```

This is *basically* saying "select the direct descendant  `div` of `#toast-containers` elements that **also** have a `.toast-custom` class applied." Since that is more specific than the framework's rule, your rule will override, but only in that case. -- (`#toast-containers` that *do not* implement `.toast-custom` should not be affected.)

**From MDN**

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
>   applied.

See [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on MDN for more information.

Comment: this worked for me : `#toast-container.toast-custom > div {
`